# Dojo json select

Tags: json, dojo

I have a `dojo.xhrGet` that return an correct array of object :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");

        dojo.addOnLoad( function() {

            var name = dojo.byId("nafn");
            name.setAttribute("dojoType", "dijit.form.ComboBox");

            dojo.parser.parse(name.parent);

            dojo.xhrGet({
              url: "http://localhost:8080/App/gots",
              handleAs: "json",

              load: function(data){
                    dojo.byId("container").innerHTML = data;
                    dojo.parser.parse("container");

                    console.log(data);

                    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore( { data: data });

                    console.log(store);

                    var filteringSelect = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
                        id: "stateSelect",
                        name: "state",
                        value: "Search",
                        store: store,
                        searchAttr: "bondiuser"
                    },
                    "nafn");

            },

            onError: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            },
            headers:{"Accept":"application/json"}
            });

        });
    </script>
```

When I output to my javascript console, I can see my object when I do :

```
console.log(data);
```

But the `ItemFileReadStore` remains empty why ?

Comment: You need to show us the contents of `data` received from the server. If it's simply an array of objects, that's probably your error: the data parameter you give to ItemFileReadStore should be an object with `{identifier: "id", items: [{...}, {...}, ...]}`, where id is the name of your objects' identifier. See http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore#general-structure

Comment: The error must come from that. Here is the json string : {"bondiuser":"gilles","dna":null,"eigandi":null,"fadir":null,"faedingardagur":1306972800000,"fang":null,"harafar":"Lodinn","id":1,"kyn":"Hundur","litur":"Hvitur","modir":null,"nafn":"Bjartur","ormerki":"123123","sfiNumer":"12313123","stofnskra":false,"version":0}

Comment: That's only one object. Shouldn't your server return an array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data parameter for ItemFileReadStore should be an object with properties `identifier` and `items`.

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore( { data: {
  identifier: "bondiuser",
  items: data
}});
```

This assumes `data` is an array of objects all of which have at least a property named `bondiuser`.